# Getting error when using while loop to filter duplicates out from a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, while-loop, iteration

I'm trying to open a txt file and get all the words in it, assign it to a list, and filter the list of duplicates. The code in the snippet is what I thought would work, but I'm getting a traceback error and it says list index is out of range. How can I modify my code to avoid that error?

Any help is appreciated.

```py
fname = input("Enter file name: ") 
fh = open("romeo.txt") 
lst = list() 
for line in fh: 
    nlst = (line.rstrip()).split() 
    lst = lst + nlst

for i in [*range(len(lst))]: 
    if lst.count(lst[i]) > 1: 
        while lst.count(lst[i]) > 1: 
            print(lst[i]) 
            lst.remove(lst[i]) 
    else: 
        continue 
         
print(lst)
```

edit 1:

Okay so I thought the cause of the problem was lst.count(lst[i]) having a value of one or more and the inequality is (>1) so it's saying that it's out of range, but I tried 0 instead of 1, and it still gave me the same error.

[vsc snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jWjZ.jpg)

Comment: I suspect that you have more than one thing going on. First, I don't think you can do `for line in fh:`. You have to do `fh.read()` or `fh.readline()` to get the contents.  Second, remember that `len` gets the total number of elements, but list indexes starts on 0.

Comment: Youssef, can you paste your code in the question? It'll be a lot easier for you to get help over here. You can find how to format your code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: # fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open("romeo.txt")
lst = list()
for line in fh:
    nlst = (line.rstrip()).split()
    lst = lst + nlst

for i in [*range(len(lst))]:
    if lst.count(lst[i]) > 1:
        while lst.count(lst[i]) > 1:           
            print(lst[i])
            lst.remove(lst[i])
            
    else:
        continue

print(lst)

Comment: okay so i tried indenting and it's not working :/

Comment: Done, I've put it into your OP.

Comment: @RamonK of course you can do `for line in fh`; that's the canonical way of iterating through lines in a file.

Comment: @larsks Oh, didn't know. Thanks! By the way... what canon? Can you link it for me? All the tutorial I've seen say to use `read`, `readline`, `readlines`, and I wrongly assumed you would get bytes by iterating the file.

Comment: @RamonK A file is an [iterator](https://peps.python.org/pep-0234/#file-iterators) that yields lines in the file. So I guess the direct answer is "since PEP 234", but you'll find examples of that idiom all over the place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but i'm getting a traceback error and it says list index is out of range

First, whenever you're asking about a traceback, include the actual error message in your question. In this case, that looks like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../countwords.py", line 9, in <module>
    if lst.count(lst[i]) > 1:
                 ~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
```

There are several issues that get us into this situation. Broadly, you're iterating over the number of words in the document. For each word, you're using `lst.count` to find occurrences of the word in `lst`...and then removing duplicates. Whenever you find a duplicate, `lst` gets shorter, but your outer loop doesn't know this. Eventually, you ask for `lst[i]` when `i` is larger than the length of the list and your code explodes.

We can fix this while preserving your current logic by making a couple of changes.

- First, let's fix that outer loop; you've written `for i in [*range(len(lst)]`, but that's operationally equivalent to `for i in range(lst)`, which is simpler to read.
- Instead of trying to update `lst`, let's populate a new variable `lst_no_dupes`; this avoids issues with modifying `lst` while at the same time trying to iterate over it:
- Instead of using `lst.count`, we can use the `in` operator to check for the presence of a word in a list.

Those changes get us:

```
lst_no_dupes = []
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if lst[i] not in lst_no_dupes:
        lst_no_dupes.append(lst[i])

print(lst_no_dupes)
```

This works, but it's inefficient, because checking to see if a word is contained in the list is an *O(n)* operation. As the number of words grows larger, it will take longer and longer to look up items in the list.

There's a much simpler way to produce a list of unique items from a list as long as you don't care about their order: [just turn them into a set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists):

```
fh = open("romeo.txt") 
lst = list()
for line in fh:
    nlst = (line.rstrip()).split()
    lst = lst + nlst

lst = set(lst)
print(lst)
```

A [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) is "an unordered collection of distinct objects"; lookups in a set are *O(1)* so the time required to check for a duplicate is independent of the number of words.

---

Ultimately, you could simplify everything down to this:

```
with open('romeo.txt') as fh:
  lst = set(word for line in fh for word in line.split())
print(lst)
```

Here, we're iterating over lines in the file (`for line in fd`) and then words in each line (`for word in line.split()`). This is an example of a [generator expression](https://peps.python.org/pep-0289/) (which is like a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)).